# Function sort order by outside main function in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

This is my code demo. I have a function sort_order outside main (def sort). In main, I call sort_order and send parameters order = 'car' but it is errored( `TypeError: sort_order() missing 1 required positional argument: 'e'`). But `e` is self. I can't move function sort_order inside main becacause of a few reason in my project. Please help me in addition to tips move to def sort_order inside main. Thanks for helping me

```py
def sort_order(e, order):
  return e[order]

def sort():
  order = 'car' # Can change
  cars = [
    {'car': 'Ford', 'year': 2005},
    {'car': 'Mitsubishi', 'year': 2000},
    {'car': 'BMW', 'year': 2019},
    {'car': 'VW', 'year': 2011}
  ]
  
  #root cause in here
  return cars.sort(key=sort_order(order=order))


result = sort()
print(result)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `But e is self.` Is this part of a class? If so, it would really help to make that part of the example. Otherwise the answer is simply `cars.sort(key=lambda d: d[order])` or `cars.sort(key=lambda d: sort_order(order, d))`. (Also remember `sort()` sorts in place and returns `None`. You probable want `sorted()` for this.)

Comment: I reference and upgrade from link https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_ref_list_sort4 . You can see `e` in this def